# Wait until DOS command execution has finished - Java

Tags: java, mysql, import, wait, dump

I am trying to import a large amount of **.dmp** files in a MySQL DB and since there are more than 250 files that have to be imported I wrote an app to automate the execution of the 250+ DOS commands. The code for it:

```
String baseCommand = "cmd /c MySQL -h localhost -u root amateurstable < ";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(baseCommand + filePath);
```

It does execute the commands it is supposed to. The problem is that some of the **.dmp** files are larger than 100MB, but the code above does not wait until the execution of the command is finished.

When it executes the import command for a large file it does not wait until the import is over and executes the next command right after. This causes a lot of headaches in terms of responsiveness of the computer.

The question is how to make it wait until the execution of the command completes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(baseCommand + filePath, "");
Process start = pb.start();
start.waitFor();
```

Comment: Runtime returns Process as well, so he can achieve his goal using Runtime as well as ProcessBuilder. There are some benefits of using ProcessBuilder though, so in the end, that's a good suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Runtime.exec returns a [Process](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object that has a waitFor() method.

> waitFor() 
>              causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated.

Since you already have that Process object you could just add the call to waitFor()

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(baseCommand + filePath);
p.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 2):

use [`process.waitFor()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Apache Commons Exec as well?

http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html

Seems like you have your processing well in hand, but I think it's a little easier to work with as a wrapper over the Runtime exec.  If you needed to kill a process it can make life easier.